# What causes this call to Firebase server?

Tags: android, firebase

An Android app does not use Firebase. I have done a global search to ensure nothing has the word "firebase". However, I see the following logcat entry:

> TRuntime.C...ortBackend com.mydomain.myapp  I  Making request to: https://firebaselogging.googleapis.com/v0cc/log/batch?format=json_proto3

Could anyone offer a tip to help figure out what triggers this?

The app does not use any third-party analytics or advertising packages.

**Update [2023-05-25]**

Here are the dependencies of the app:

```
   implementation "androidx.activity:activity:1.7.1"
    implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment:1.5.7'
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.5.3"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.5.3"
    implementation "androidx.preference:preference:1.2.0"
    implementation "androidx.datastore:datastore:1.0.0"
    implementation 'androidx.gridlayout:gridlayout:1.0.0'

    implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime:2.8.1'

    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.5.0'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:20.5.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:21.0.1'
    implementation('com.google.guava:guava:30.1.1-android') {
        exclude group: "com.google.guava"
    }

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-oss-licenses:17.0.1'

    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'

    implementation 'joda-time:joda-time:2.10.10'

    implementation 'com.github.angads25:filepicker:1.1.1'

    implementation 'commons-io:commons-io:2.5'

    implementation 'com.google.android.flexbox:flexbox:3.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.ads.consent:consent-library:1.0.8'

    implementation 'com.github.hedzr:android-file-chooser:d7b831bf0a'


    implementation('com.google.http-client:google-http-client-gson:1.26.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
    }
    implementation('com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.26.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
    }
    implementation('com.google.apis:google-api-services-drive:v3-rev136-1.25.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
    }

    implementation 'com.android.billingclient:billing:6.0.0'

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.11'
```

**Update [2023-05-25]**

I started to look into this after I observed the app crashes consistently following:

> Making request to:
> https://firebaselogging.googleapis.com/v0cc/log/batch?format=json_proto3

As far as I know, this started to happen only recently after I updated some dependencies.
Here is the crash:

```
StrictMode policy violation: android.os.strictmode.UntaggedSocketViolation: Untagged socket detected; use TrafficStats.setThreadSocketTag() to track all network usage
    at android.os.StrictMode.onUntaggedSocket(StrictMode.java:2023)
    at com.android.server.NetworkManagementSocketTagger.tag(NetworkManagementSocketTagger.java:82)
    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.tagSocket(BlockGuardOs.java:50)
    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.socket(BlockGuardOs.java:313)
    at libcore.io.IoBridge.socket(IoBridge.java:640)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketCreate(PlainSocketImpl.java:124)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.create(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:128)
    at java.net.Socket.createImpl(Socket.java:489)
    at java.net.Socket.getImpl(Socket.java:552)
    at java.net.Socket.setSoTimeout(Socket.java:1180)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:139)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:112)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:184)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:126)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:95)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:281)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:224)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:461)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:127)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:258)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getOutputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:218)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:26)
    at com.google.android.datatransport.cct.CctTransportBackend.doSend(CctTransportBackend.java:303)
    at com.google.android.datatransport.cct.CctTransportBackend.$r8$lambda$bLAzIpNF4NtapXlUpPVGhzxyNT8(Unknown Source:0)
    at com.google.android.datatransport.cct.CctTransportBackend$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.apply(Unknown Source:4)
    at com.google.android.datatransport.runtime.retries.Retries.retry(Retries.java:54)
    at com.google.android.datatransport.cct.CctTransportBackend.send(CctTransportBackend.java:372)
    at com.google.android.datatransport.runtime.scheduling.jobscheduling.Uploader.logAndUpdateState(Uploader.java:146)
    at com.google.android.datatransport.runtime.scheduling.jobscheduling.Uploader.lambda$upload$1$com-google-android-datatransport-runtime-scheduling-jobscheduling-Uploader(Uploader.java:105)
    at com.google.android.datatransport.runtime.scheduling.jobscheduling.Uploader$$ExternalSyntheticLambda2.run(Unknown Source:8)
    at com.google.android.datatransport.runtime.SafeLoggingExecutor$SafeLoggingRunnable.run(SafeLoggingExecutor.java:47)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

**Update [2023-07-21]**

The complete logcat entry of the Firebase call that causes the crash:

> I/TRuntime.CctTransportBackend: Making request to:
> https://firebaselogging.googleapis.com/v0cc/log/batch?format=json_proto3

Comment: A quick search in the code points to Performance Monitoring and Remote Config calling this end point. Are you sure you're not using these, or maybe something more common like Firebase Cloud Messaging?

Comment: I have just searched for "Firebase", "Cloud", and "Messaging" globally and found nothing. I will examine all the dependencies to see if any of them are related to this.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I have updated the question by adding the dependencies of the app.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*firebaser here*

tl;dr: many non-Firebase Google use the https://firebaselogging.googleapis.com/ endpoint to log data to Google's servers, so calls to that endpoint do not have to originate from Firebase SDKs.

---

Most Google developer products that come with an SDK use a common infrastructure for logging application specific data from within the app back to Google. They use common endpoints for sending this logging, so that they can combine API calls from multiple SDKs into a single call to the logging backend - reducing/amortize the overhead of the logging.

At some point many of the SDKs for Google developer products switched over from a Google-branded endpoint to using a Firebase-branded endpoint. But the data flows is the same either way, and calls to the https://firebaselogging.googleapis.com/ does not necessarily mean that the product uses a Firebase SDK.

This is indeed confusing though, so I raised an issue internally to consider changing to a single Google-branded endpoint again, or to use a per-product endpoint (which would lose some of the amortization benefits mentioned earlier.

Comment: Thank you for the elucidation. Do you mean one of the dependencies from Google initiates this call? If so, is there a way to find out which one? I feel that this is a new issue after updating some dependencies recently because The crash caused by "StrictMode policy violation: android.os.strictmode.UntaggedSocketViolation: Untagged socket detected" consistently follows "Making request to: https://firebaselogging.googleapis.com/v0cc/log/batch?format=json_proto3".  I am going to update my question to add this piece of information.

Comment: Hmmm... I have no idea which SDK is making those requests. If it was anything from Firebase I'd expect to see proof of that in the stack trace, but this stack trace seems devoid of any identifiable SDK. I have no idea how to further troubleshoot that unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue.

My app was using google MLKit API.

I noticed that after every network call my app has made, some dependency triggered a network call to

> https://firebaselogging.googleapis.com/v0cc/log/batch?format=json_proto3

, To remove it:

1. Open AndroidManifest.xml
2. In the AndroidManifest file, open the bottom tab of "Merged Manifest"
3. In the Merged Manifest file,  look for the following dependency -

   ```
   <service
       android:name="com.google.android.datatransport.runtime.scheduling.jobscheduling.JobInfoSchedulerService"
       android:exported="false"
       android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE" >
   </service>
   ```
4. Double click it, it should take you to the relevant dependency Manifest file
5. Comment the service out
6. Then run your app and see if the network call is still there.